# Godot radial TextureProgress does not fully fill in after value of 61?

Tags: godot

So i've been trying to create a radial TextureProgress node in Godot engine. I created two simple png textures of two different colored circles. Both textures are the same size and contain alpha background.

I apply one texture to the "under" and the other one as "progress". Everything seems to work fine and the progress gets filled in while the value rises until value is 61 (max 100 range). The progress then just disappears. However; once i hit 100 (exactly, not 99) the progress comes back and is fully filled in.

Why am i getting this gap of nothing between 61 and 99.9?

Comment: Can you post the script where you alter the progress value variable? I will try to replicate this later.

Comment: So there really is no code, thats the thing.. all im doing is playing with the "value" entry in the UI. Here is an example - If you increase past 61+ the progress will disappear
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1wb6kt44KxsVkKNwFWwdYqaKGhGgCo8VE:

Answer (score 2):

looks like this is a known issue:
https://github.com/godotengine/godot/issues/17102